# Search for numbers in an array with a certain amount

Tags: javascript

i have an array for example [10, 5, 6, 3], also a variable b = 13, I wanna calculate the sum of each element of the array, if the sum equal = b(13) returns true, i know first and last elements sum = 13. How can I check which pair of element's sum?

Comment: you want to check for sum of two values in `array` or sum of any number of values?

Comment: sum of two values in array

Answer (score 0):

You can use this algorithm to check if two values in array have the given sum or not.

```js
function pairWithSum(array,sum){
  //sort the array
  const arr = array.sort((a,b) => a -b);
  while(arr.length > 1){
    if(arr[0] + arr[arr.length - 1] > sum) arr.pop()
    if(arr[0] + arr[arr.length - 1] < sum) arr.shift()
    if(arr[0] + arr[arr.length - 1] === sum) return true
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(pairWithSum([10,3,5,6,1],1))
console.log(pairWithSum([10,3,5,6,1],11))
console.log(pairWithSum([10,3,5,6,1],13));
console.log(pairWithSum([10,3,5,6,1],55))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table for the missing parts and return if found.

```js
function check(array, sum) {
    var hash = {},
        i = 0,
        v;
        
    while (i < array.length) {
        v = array[i];
        if (hash[v]) return true;
        hash[sum - v] = true;
        ++i;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(check([10, 5, 6, 3], 13));
console.log(check([10, 5, 6, 3], 17));
```